# onClick and view issue

Tags: android, view, onclick

i have some buttons had been added programmatically and setted on click method as below :

```
0 public RelativeLayout popupLayout;

1  moreBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
2         public void onClick(View arg0) {
3             popupLayout.startAnimation(popupAnim);
4             popupLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
5             popupRel.removeAllViews();
6
7              ...
8  }
```

the method has continue.but i have problem about lines 3 and 4 as LogCat says and when i delete them the method works fine.but if not,the app crashes as LogCat below :

---

```
08-15 14:27:51.034: E/AndroidRuntime(30355): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-15 14:27:51.034: E/AndroidRuntime(30355): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-15 14:27:51.034: E/AndroidRuntime(30355):    at com.example.mysqlex.Content$4.onClick(Content.java:300)
08-15 14:27:51.034: E/AndroidRuntime(30355):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4102)
08-15 14:27:51.034: E/AndroidRuntime(30355):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17085)
08-15 14:27:51.034: E/AndroidRuntime(30355):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-15 14:27:51.034: E/AndroidRuntime(30355):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-15 14:27:51.034: E/AndroidRuntime(30355):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
08-15 14:27:51.034: E/AndroidRuntime(30355):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
08-15 14:27:51.034: E/AndroidRuntime(30355):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-15 14:27:51.034: E/AndroidRuntime(30355):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-15 14:27:51.034: E/AndroidRuntime(30355):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
08-15 14:27:51.034: E/AndroidRuntime(30355):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
08-15 14:27:51.034: E/AndroidRuntime(30355):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: popupLayout is null, i suspect

Comment: no i had defined it in onCreate at first as popupRel=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.popupRel); and

Comment: You may have initialized `popupRel`, but you didn't initialize `popupLayout`. Those are two different variables! Show the code where you initialize **both** and I believe you. What layout do you have, Relative or Linear? Because both are shown in your code, and you use both, but I dont see you initializing them anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you didn't initialize `popupLayout` so first initialize in `onCreate`  method after `setContentView` line as

```
popupLayout = new RelativeLayout();
```

or from xml id as

```
popupLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.popupLayout);
```

Comment: no i had defined it in onCreate at first as popupRel=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.popupRel); and

Comment: @user3543201 also initialize popupLayout.because your popupLayout is null.